# WebSockets and MS-SQL

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish-4

WebSockets whenever execute SQL queries, at that point of time, WebSocket session expires and then the page gets refreshed and a new session is created. 
I do not want my page to refresh.

Comment: @Philipp: WebSockets whenever execute SQL queries, at that point of time, WebSocket session expires and then the page gets refreshed and a new session is created, can you help me in this ? 
I do not want my page to refresh.

Comment: Please simplify the sourcecode of your servlet to the minimum which is necessary to demonstrate the problem and then post it. For more information about how to best ask for help with "my code doesn't do what I want it to do" problems, see http://sscce.org/